# Service Principal permissions replace each other instead of getting added together in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have 2 functions in Powershell to add 2 separate permissions to my service principal in Azure AD.

Here's the first:

```
function Add-User-Impersonation {
    
    param(
        $App
    )

    $AzureManagementAPI = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "41094075-9dad-400e-a0bd-54e686782033","Scope"

    $RequiredAccess = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
    $RequiredAccess.ResourceAppId = "797f4846-ba00-4fd7-ba43-dac1f8f63013"
    $RequiredAccess.ResourceAccess = $AzureManagementAPI

    Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $App.ObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess @($RequiredAccess)


    Write-Output "User-Impersonation Added"

    return $App
}
```

And Here's the second:

```
function Add-Offline-Access {
    
    param(
        $App
    )

    $myappId = $App.ObjectId
    $MSGraph = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" }

    # Retrieve the ID of the 'offline_access' permission from Microsoft Graph
    $offlineAccessPermission = $MSGraph.Oauth2Permissions | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq 'offline_access' }
    $Graph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
    $Graph.ResourceAppId = $MSGraph.AppId
    $Per1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList $offlineAccessPermission.Id,"Scope"
    $Graph.ResourceAccess = $Per1
    Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $myappId -RequiredResourceAccess $Graph

    Write-Output "Offline-Access Added"

    return $App
}
```

[Azure Portal 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT86l.png)

[Azure Portal 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WgDx.png)

See my Azure Portal when I run each function. When I run Add-Offline-Access, it will add the "offline-access" permission under Microsoft Graph. Then, when I run Add-User-Impersonation, it will replace the "offline-access" permission with the "User Impersonation" permission under Azure Service Management. I would like to have both permissions at the same time.

Does anyone know why this bug is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** that: `Set-AzureADApplication` replaces the complete `RequiredResourceAccess` property of the application with the new value provided in each function.

To add two separate permissions (*Microsoft Graph and Windows Azure Service Management API*) make use of below PowerShell script:

```
$MgAPI = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Windows Azure Service Management API" }
$GraphAPI = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" }

$AzureMg = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$AzureMg.ResourceAppId = $MgAPI.AppId
 
$Graph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$Graph.ResourceAppId = $GraphAPI.AppId

$delPermission1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "41094075-9dad-400e-a0bd-54e686782033","Scope" 
$delPermission2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182","Scope" 

$AzureMg.ResourceAccess = $delPermission1 
$Graph.ResourceAccess = $delPermission2

$ObjectID = "dcac094f-f07c-4f81-946e-7f60a3b7003e"
$AADApplication = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $ObjectID
 
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $ObjectID -RequiredResourceAccess $AzureMg, $Graph
```

Azure Service Management and Microsoft Graph API permissions added to the application successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm having a similar problem where I'm trying to add other permissions and those are getting replaced as well. I created a new question, could you take a look over there?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78049799/service-principal-permissions-replace-each-other-instead-of-getting-added-togeth

Thank you