# Service Principal permissions replace each other instead of getting added together in powershell, part 2

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have 2 functions in Powershell to add separate permissions to my service principal in Azure AD. Here's the first:

```
function Add-Permissions {
    
    param(
        $App
    )
    
    $SPforApp = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $App.AppId -PasswordCredentials @($PasswordCredential)

    $targetServicePrincipalName = 'Microsoft Graph'
    $targetSp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($TargetServicePrincipalName)'"

    $appPermissionsRequired = @('User.Read.All','Group.Read.All','GroupMember.Read.All',`
    'GroupMember.ReadWrite.All','Directory.Read.All','AuditLog.Read.All')

    $RoleAssignments = @()

    Foreach ($AppPermission in $appPermissionsRequired) {
    $RoleAssignment = $targetSp.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq $AppPermission}
    $RoleAssignments += $RoleAssignment
    }

    $ResourceAccessObjects = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]'

    foreach ($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments) {
    $resourceAccess = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess"
    $resourceAccess.Id = $RoleAssignment.Id
    $resourceAccess.Type = 'Role'
    $ResourceAccessObjects.Add($resourceAccess)
    }
    
    $requiredResourceAccess = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
    $requiredResourceAccess.ResourceAppId = $targetSp.AppId
    $requiredResourceAccess.ResourceAccess = $ResourceAccessObjects

    # set the required resource access
    Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $App.ObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredResourceAccess
    Start-Sleep -s 1

    # grant the required resource access
    foreach ($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments) {
    Write-Output -InputObject ('Granting admin consent for App Role: {0}' -f $($RoleAssignment.Value))
    New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $SPforApp.ObjectId -Id $RoleAssignment.Id -PrincipalId $SPforApp.ObjectId -ResourceId $targetSp.ObjectId
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    }

    Write-Output "Permissions Added"

    return $App
}
```

And here's the second:

```
function Add-Two-Permissions {
    
    param(
        $App
    )

    $MgAPI = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Windows Azure Service Management API" }
    $GraphAPI = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" }

    $AzureMg = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
    $AzureMg.ResourceAppId = $MgAPI.AppId
 
    $Graph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
    $Graph.ResourceAppId = $GraphAPI.AppId

    $delPermission1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "41094075-9dad-400e-a0bd-54e686782033","Scope" 
    $delPermission2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182","Scope" 

    $AzureMg.ResourceAccess = $delPermission1 
    $Graph.ResourceAccess = $delPermission2
 
    Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $App.ObjectID -RequiredResourceAccess $AzureMg, $Graph

    Write-Output "Two Permissions Added"

    return $App
}
```

These two functions are replacing each other instead of adding together. I'm looking to have them add the permissions together. It would be mainly taking the permissions:

```
$appPermissionsRequired = @('User.Read.All','Group.Read.All','GroupMember.Read.All',`
    'GroupMember.ReadWrite.All','Directory.Read.All','AuditLog.Read.All')
```

and adding them to the second function.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Set-AzureADApplication** overwrites the existing *RequiredResourceAccess* property of the application with the **most recent** value provided.

You need to provide **all** the required permissions to *Set-AzureADApplication* at once and execute it in a **single operation** by making use of below script:

```
$myApp = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq 'MyFebApp'"

$targetSpGraph = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'"
$appPermissionsRequired = @('User.Read.All','Group.Read.All','GroupMember.Read.All','GroupMember.ReadWrite.All','Directory.Read.All','AuditLog.Read.All')

$RoleAssignmentsGraph = @()

foreach ($AppPermission in $appPermissionsRequired) {
    $RoleAssignmentGraph = $targetSpGraph.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq $AppPermission }
    $RoleAssignmentsGraph += $RoleAssignmentGraph
}

$ResourceAccessObjectsGraph = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]'

foreach ($RoleAssignmentGraph in $RoleAssignmentsGraph) {
    $resourceAccessGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess"
    $resourceAccessGraph.Id = $RoleAssignmentGraph.Id
    $resourceAccessGraph.Type = 'Role'
    $ResourceAccessObjectsGraph.Add($resourceAccessGraph)
}

$requiredResourceAccessGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$requiredResourceAccessGraph.ResourceAppId = $targetSpGraph.AppId
$requiredResourceAccessGraph.ResourceAccess = $ResourceAccessObjectsGraph

$delPermissionGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182","Scope" 
$requiredResourceAccessGraph.ResourceAccess += $delPermissionGraph

$targetSpAzure = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Windows Azure Service Management API" }
$delPermissionAzure = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "41094075-9dad-400e-a0bd-54e686782033","Scope" 

$requiredResourceAccessAzure = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$requiredResourceAccessAzure.ResourceAppId = $targetSpAzure.AppId
$requiredResourceAccessAzure.ResourceAccess = @($delPermissionAzure)

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $myApp.ObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredResourceAccessGraph, $requiredResourceAccessAzure
Write-Output "Combined Permissions Added"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, all permissions **added** successfully to the application like this:

[image]

You can grant **admin consent** to the above permissions by running this CLI command:

```bash
az ad app permission admin-consent --id appObjID
```

To  **confirm**  that, I checked the same in Portal where admin consent granted successfully like this:

[image]